# iterm2 emacsclient keybindings

Tags: emacs, key-binding, iterm2

I have just switched from using Emacs.app to emacsserver and emacsclient in terminal mode using iterm2 as my terminal emulator. I am having some trouble with some keybindings though. Particularly `M-left arrow` prints the character `D`, `M-right arrow` prints `C`, `M-up arrow` prints `A`, and `M-down arrow` prints `B`. I am using the xterm defaults for keys in iterm2 and have the left and right option keys bound to `+Esc`. This is particularly annoying in org-mode. Am I going to have to just rebind the keys in my .emacs? How would I go about doing that?